# QtCreator - Debugging as superuser on Mac OS

Tags: debugging, macos, qt

I'd like to debug an application in QtCreator on Mac OS which reads directly from hard disk (/dev/rdisk0). If I run this app from Terminal using sudo ./MyApp, it's working, however when I debugging it under QtCreator, it fails due to lack of permissions.

I tried to launch QtCreator itself from terminal using "sudo open QtCreator.app", but it didn't help.

Please suggest how to get around it.

Serge.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you installed QtCreator into /Developer/Applications, you probably have to do:

```
sudo /Developer/Applications/Qt/QtCreator.app/Contents/MacOS/QtCreator
```

If QtCreator is a Carbon application, then you might need to execute:

```
sudo -b /System/Library/Frameworks/Carbon.framework/Versions/Current/Support/LaunchCFMApp /Developer/Applications/Qt/QtCreator.app
```

See also: [Open GUI applications as root - Mac Forums](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/os-x-darwin-development/311-open-gui-applications-root.html).